# any way to run grep backwards, i.e. from the end of the file and up?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

I have a 70G+ log file, and i'd like the most recent entries (apache log append new items at the end) that match a pattern. i can either:

```
run grep | tail
```

or

```
run tail | grep
```

Option 1 will take forever. Option 2 may return nothing, then I will have to increase the count for tail and keep running until I get something.

If I could grep from the last line up to the first, it would be ideal. But I could not find any option on grep's man page.

Is there any trick to do that? either on grep alone or with any other combination of linux tools?

Comment: Are line numbers important?

Comment: Related: [Reverse grepping](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146100/80216).

Answer (score 7):

I think the command that will best help you is tac: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac

As it states: 
tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

So you could pipe it to grep and match nnn number of lines before stopping, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

That's a big file. You should rotate those logs more often.

If `tac` is too slow, you could pick a programming language with a `seek` command (perl, for instance), then:

- open the file
- seek to the end
- iteratively:

  - seek backwards some amount (4K, or larger)
  - read that amount of text
  - split on newlines, and search for whatever.